# Pandas apply() custom function using more than one column as "input"

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Perhaps looking at this quick example will help you to understand what I try to do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,50,70,40], "B": [20,30,10,15,20,30]})


def _custom_function(X):    
    # whatever... just for the purpose of the example
    # but I need X to be the actual df and not a series

    Y = sum((X['A'] / X['B']) + (0.2 * X['B']))   
    return Y


df['C'] = df.rolling(2).apply(_custom_function, axis=0)
```

When the custom function is called, X is Series type and only the first columns of the df. Is it possible to pass a df trought the apply function ?

**Edit: it is possible to use rolling().apply():**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,50,70,40], "B": [20,30,10,15,20,30]})


def _custom_function(X):    
    # whatever... just for the purpose of the example
    Y = sum(0.2 * X)    
    return Y


df['C'] = df['A'].rolling(2).apply(_custom_function)
```

**Second edit: list comprehension with rolling does not behave as expected**

```
for x in df.rolling(3):
    print(x)
```

As you can see in the example below both approaches don't give the same output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,50,70,40], "B": [20,30,10,15,20,30]})
df['C'] = 0.2


def _custom_function_df(X):    
    # whatever... just for the purpose of the example
    # but I need X to be the actual df and not a series
    Y = sum(X['C'] * X['B'])
    return Y

def _custom_function_series(X):    
    # whatever... just for the purpose of the example
    # but I need X to be the actual df and not a series
    Y = sum(0.2 * X)
    return Y


df['result'] = df['B'].rolling(3).apply(_custom_function_series)

df['result2'] = [x.pipe(_custom_function_df) for x in df.rolling(3, min_periods=3)]
```

**The list comprehension with rolling output the first lines (no expected NaN), but starts the correct rolling ONLY after len(x) = 3, the rolling window.**

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass DataFrame to function:

```
df['C'] = _custom_function(df)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
df['C'] = df.pipe(_custom_function)

print (df)
    A   B         C
0  10  20  4.500000
1  20  30  6.666667
2  30  10  5.000000
3  50  15  6.333333
4  70  20  7.500000
5  40  30  7.333333
```

EDIT: [`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) working by each column separately, so cannot used here.

Possible solution:

```
df['C'] = [x.pipe(_custom_function) for x in df.rolling(2)]
print (df)
    A   B          C
0  10  20   4.500000
1  20  30  11.166667
2  30  10  11.666667
3  50  15  11.333333
4  70  20  13.833333
5  40  30  14.833333
```

EDIT: If seems bug, default `rolling` working like `min_periods=1`.

Here is solution (hack):

```
df['result'] = df['B'].rolling(3).apply(_custom_function_series)

df['result2']=[x.pipe(_custom_function_df) if len(x)==3 else np.nan for x in df.rolling(3)]

print (df)
    A   B    C  result  result2
0  10  20  0.2     NaN      NaN
1  20  30  0.2     NaN      NaN
2  30  10  0.2    12.0     12.0
3  50  15  0.2    11.0     11.0
4  70  20  0.2     9.0      9.0
5  40  30  0.2    13.0     13.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think pipe() is what I was looking for because my end goal is to do something like:

df.rolling(n).pipe(_custom_function)

Comment: @plonfat - some problem with solution?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, yes unfortunately. 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'pipe'.
However, rolling does have the attribute 'apply' but this goes back to my initial problem.

Comment: @plonfat - in rolling apply it is imposibble.

Comment: @plonfat - Can you test `df['C'] = [x.pipe(_custom_function) for x in df.rolling(2)]` ?

Comment: it is possible, please see EDIT in the question. Thanks for the other suggestion, I see how you would like to approach it, will try it right now.

Comment: having a final issue with your list comprehension solution. See the edit above.

Comment: @plonfat - Do you think need `df.rolling(3, min_periods=1)` ?

Comment: not sure it changes anything. Currently during first iteration output line 0, next iteration lines 0 1, then 0 1 2 and only after start the "true" rolling 1 2 3, 2 3 4, 3 4 5 etc etc....

Comment: tried df['C'] = [x.pipe(_custom_function) if len(x) == 3 for x in df.rolling(3)] doesn't work

Comment: @plonfat - Not understand, if use `min_periods=1` is is expected first iter has one row, second 2 rows, third, foutrth, fifth.. has 3 rows.

Comment: just edited the question that shows my problem.

Comment: So you believe that it is a bug ? Thank you very much, everyting working now !

Comment: @plonfat - Be free ask in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)